# how to convert String to Double in jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to convert String to Double value in jasper Reports?
  I am having two fields in .jrxml file like below

```
    <field name="secRate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="secPrice" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

i need to subtract both the field

```
   $V{Variable} = $F{secRate} - SF{secPrice}
```

i tried this way but not working

```
  (new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{mktVal})))
```

any idea? please help me guys..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert String to Double value in jasper Reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680178/how-to-convert-string-to-double-value-in-jasper-reports)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `mktVal` field is a String, you can try using `Double.valueOf(${mktVal})`.

Comment: can you tell me how to convert to BigDecimal(from string to BigDecimal for above question)?

Comment: you can use new BigDecimal(${mktVal})

Comment: I tried this way but not working "new BigDecimal($F{secAcrruedAmt})+ (new BigDecimal($F{secPrice}))".. any idea?

Comment: i got below error: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: For BigDecimal operations you must use the add(), subtract(), multiply() and divide() methods of the BigDecimal class. In your case:
$V{Variable} = new BigDecimal($F{secRate}).subtract(new BigDecimal($F{secPrice}))

Answer (score 1):

1. Set Text Field Expression: `Double.parseDouble($F{PARAM})`
2. Set Expression Class: `java.lang.Double`
3. Add `rt.jar` (from java runtime) to classpath [`Tools >> Options >> Classpath`]
4. And Compile

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Double.valueOf(${mktVal}).
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this one - `($F{PARAM}.trim().isEmpty()) ? 0.0 : new Double($F{PARAM})`

Comment: Vijay N, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.