# How to convert String to Double value in jasper Reports?

Tags: java

How to convert String to Double value in jasper Reports? I am having two fields in .jrxml file like below

```
<field name="secRate" class="java.lang.String"/> 
<field name="secPrice" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

i need to subtract both the field

```
     $V{Variable} = $F{secRate} - SF{secPrice}
```

i tried this way but not working

```
      (new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{mktVal})))
```

any idea? please help me guys..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{secRate}) + Double.parseDouble($F{secPrice}))
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do it for BigDecimal as well.

Comment: I cannot express how much this helped me! I use jasperSoft Studio and it was very particular about how this expression was worded. I will also add that I made the mistake of trying to change the class of the fields to java.lang.Double when java.lang.String is what you really want. I kept getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "" before. Maybe that will help someone else out there!