# How Convert String parameter to Double in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am having a string value(12.023) as String and I want to convert it to double and round this value and print on textfield, How to do this.

```
my textfield expression is -> $P{totalAvgBytes}
Expression class -> java.lang.String
```

What i have to do in

```
Pattern Expr - > ?????
```

I tired like Pattern `Expr = Double.valueOf($P{totalAvgBytes}).`

But it throws error like double can not be cast to string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert String to Double value in jasper Reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680178/how-to-convert-string-to-double-value-in-jasper-reports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
""+Math.round((Double.valueOf($P{totalAvg}))) . It will do that.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DecimalFormat class instead.  It should automatically cast to a String.  It will take care of any rounding as well.

new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(Double.valueOf($P{totalAvgBytes})